# Scroll not working on Android Chrome only

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome

For some reason scroll doesn't work on Android Devices in Chrome browser only.

You can see the site at Peshkuiarte.com/mobile

I have tried:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').css('touch-action', 'auto');
  });
```

I can't seem to figure it out ... Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By scroll do you mean dragging the page with your finger on mobile?

You've set `-webkit-user-drag: none;` as an inline style for body, which might be the cause.

It's a Webkit-specific property:

> ### CSS property: `-webkit-user-drag`
>
> #### Description
>
> Specifies that an entire element should be draggable instead of its contents.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> -webkit-user-drag: auto | element | none;
> ```
>
> #### Values
>
> - `auto` The default dragging behavior is used.
> - `element` The entire element is draggable instead of its contents.
> - `none` The element cannot be dragged at all.

It's supported by Chrome 1-17 and Safari 3-5.1: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-webkit-user-drag

Comment: this was it, I don't understand though why are those properties set anyway? Thank you for your help

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for ... :)

Answer (score 4):

we had same problem on Chrome 40.0... and we fixed with css only solution. Maybe it is not clean but works for us:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    html, body {
        z-index: 0 !important;
        overflow: scroll !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have found `touch-action: none` added on `body` element.
Removing it enabled scrolling in android chrome.

> ### Summary
>
> The `touch-action` CSS property specifies whether, and in
>   what ways, a given region can be manipulated by the user (for
>   instance, by panning or zooming).

Source: *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action*

Hope it helps people dealing with legacy code :)

Answer (score 2):

**e.preventDefault**

```
function handlerSwipe(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(handlerTouch){
    if(e.changedTouches[0].clientX>=110)
    toggle.checked=true;
    else toggle.checked=false;
  }
  return false;
  }
  window.addEventListener("touchmove", handlerSwipe, false);
```

This was the code i used for creating a swipeable navigation drawer because of this scrolling was not working .Just removing the `e.preventDefault();` from the above code solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure about the question, you say "scroll" but the accepted answer is talking about "drag". So I am going to give you what I think you are asking (not being able to scroll within an area on a mobile).

The simplest solution is a CSS one rather than a JS one. If you have an area on your page that you need to scroll, for example a code block on a tech blog you can set position relative on the area and have overflow-x set to auto. On the body you will need to have it not move when you touch the screen.

`pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}`

`html,body{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}`

You can see this solution working on my blog if you look at the code snippet sections and try and scroll on them via chrome mobile.(http://fullstack.life/mapping_arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

**pointer-events**

I came across another issue today and I'm going to leave this here for reference. If the element with the `overflow-y: scroll;` either sets its `pointer-events: none;` or inherits it, then it won't work either. On this layer, pointer events need to be re-enabled with:

```
pointer-events: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for this issue that worked for me.

When you call the niceScroll function  `$("body").niceScroll();`  in your javascript class, it appears to add an inline style of: `overflow-y: visible` on your body element (because it is inline, it overrides any previous `overflow: hidden` that you may have written in your css file.

Simply add `overflow: hidden ! important` in the css of your **body** element.

Also, make sure that your **html** element has style of

```
overflow: hidden;
touch-action: none;
```